# how to make month view calendar like google calendar?

Tags: android

i want to make month view calendar like google calendar month view.
[image]any source code Or any help how can i start ?its working is same like as google calendar.if you don't getting any idea then i am putting image for this.

Comment: GooGLE, I'm also looking for the same. If you find solution pls help me.

Comment: You're Google. You should know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project source code hosted on google code, see, if it fullfil your needs:

http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

Comment: hey jeet this is not view like i explain this.i know about this code but i want to make like google calendar month view